# Editing rows value of a DataFrame based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and want to edit the value of a row based on the conditions. The DataFrame looks like following:

```
ID      ABCD_ID STATUS
83590   IX1655  APPROVAL_A
83590   IX1655  FINAL-APPROVAL_A
82042   IX1656  APPROVAL_A
82042   IX1656  FINAL-APPROVAL
77848   IX1666  APPROVAL_M
77848   IX1666  FINAL-APPROVAL_A
77848   IX1667  APPROVAL_A
77848   IX1667  FINAL-APPROVAL_A
```

I want to add `"DOC"` + 1,2,3 so on to the column `STATUS` based on the `ID` and `ABCD_ID` values. The logic that I applied:

```
a = 1
for i in range (len(df)-1):
    if df.ID.iloc[i] == df.ID.iloc[i+1] and df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i]== df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i+1]:
        df.STATUS.iloc[i] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i]
        df.STATUS.iloc[i+1] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i+1]
    elif  df.ID.iloc[i] == df.ID.iloc[i+1] and df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i]!= df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i+1]:
        df.STATUS.iloc[i+1] = 'DOC_'+ str(a+1) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i+1]
```

The logic works only for the rows with two identical IDS, not more.
Output:

```
   ID     ABCD_ID                 STATUS
0  83590  IX1655        DOC_1_APPROVAL_A
1  83590  IX1655  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
2  82042  IX1656        DOC_1_APPROVAL_A
3  82042  IX1656    DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL
4  77848  IX1666        DOC_1_APPROVAL_M
5  77848  IX1666  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
6  77848  IX1667  DOC_1_DOC_2_APPROVAL_A
7  77848  IX1667  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
```

I want the output look like:

```
    ID    ABCD_ID                 STATUS
0  83590  IX1655        DOC_1_APPROVAL_A
1  83590  IX1655  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
2  82042  IX1656        DOC_1_APPROVAL_A
3  82042  IX1656    DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL
4  77848  IX1666        DOC_1_APPROVAL_M
5  77848  IX1666  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
6  77848  IX1667  DOC_2_APPROVAL_A
7  77848  IX1667  DOC_2_FINAL-APPROVAL_A
```

Maybe there is an easier way to solve this? Any suggestions would highly be appreciated

Comment: I think you need to increase "i" by 2 if it gets inside the first condition (in the end of the first condition), because what may happen is that your code add Doc_2 to row 6 because of the second condition (when i == 5), after that, i increased by one and equal 6, then the first condition happens and it adds DOC_1 to line 6 and 7

Comment: @idanovadia I added i=i+2 at the end of the first condition but still getting the same output. Did you mean like?     if df.ID.iloc[i] == df.ID.iloc[i+1] and df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i]== df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i+1]:
        df.STATUS.iloc[i] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i]
        df.STATUS.iloc[i+1] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i+1]
        i=i+2

Comment: df.STATUS.iloc[0] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + ''+df.STATUS.iloc[0] 
if df.ID.iloc[i] == df.ID.iloc[i-1] and df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i]!= df.ABCD_ID.iloc[i-1]:
 df.STATUS.iloc[i] = 'DOC_'+ str(a+1) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i]
 df.STATUS.iloc[i+1] = 'DOC_'+ str(a+1) + '_'+df.STATUS.iloc[i+1]
 i = i+2
else
 df.STATUS.iloc[i] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + ''+df.STATUS.iloc[i]

Comment: Perfect @idanovadia. But I think df.STATUS.iloc[0] = 'DOC_'+ str(a) + ''+df.STATUS.iloc[0] is not needed in this case. If I keep it, for look will keep adding to iloc[o] DOC_str(a) until loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A completely different approach is to add a per-ID cumulative count to the column for a temporary data frame with duplicate rows removed. Combine it with the original data frame to fill in the missing rows. Join it to the column and you are done.
If you have a large amount of data, this is more advantageous than loop processing.

```
tmp = df[['ID','ABCD_ID']].drop_duplicates()
flg = tmp.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()+1
df = pd.concat([df, flg], axis=1)
df[0].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
df['STATUS'] = 'DOC_' + df[0].astype(str) + '_' + df['STATUS']
df

    ID  ABCD_ID     STATUS  0
0   83590   IX1655  DOC_1_APPROVAL_A    1
1   83590   IX1655  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A  1
2   82042   IX1656  DOC_1_APPROVAL_A    1
3   82042   IX1656  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL    1
4   77848   IX1666  DOC_1_APPROVAL_M    1
5   77848   IX1666  DOC_1_FINAL-APPROVAL_A  1
6   77848   IX1667  DOC_2_APPROVAL_A    2
7   77848   IX1667  DOC_2_FINAL-APPROVAL_A  2
```

Comment: a convenient way to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I had to think a bit to derive the sequence of numbers I wanted to append from the two IDs. If this is what you intend, please accept.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was intended but I would like to improve my code and find what was wrong there. Anyways thank you for your solution.